# Wordpress: List of cron jobs by plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I'm running a Wordpress blog on a `512MB VPS` and due to the lack of memory, `MySQL` crashes frequently.

I'm trying to optimize the server and I need to know what are the plugins that use cron jobs. I found the Wordpress method [_get_cron_array()](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/simple-testing/#view-all-currently-scheduled-tasks) that returns an array of all currently scheduled tasks but I don't have any information about who scheduled each of them.

So, ***How can I get the list of cron jobs by plugin ?***

Comment: check this link https://gist.github.com/stephenh1988/3919989

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/ Cron control plugin which is very useful to add and manage all the cron jobs.

Comment: This plugin don't give which plugin is reponsible for scheduling the cron job. And this is my need !

Comment: It provides the hook list so you can guess which plugin have added their hooks for the cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this plugin

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cronjob-scheduler/
```

Hope it will work for you

thanks